# How to use sed regex pattern matching

Tags: bash, sed

I'm learning bash and I'm trying to parse a webpage(https://chromium-i18n.appspot.com/ssl-address) and extract the href o
f interest using sed. The pattern I'm using is:

```
/<a\shref=\'\/ssl-address\/data\/([^\"]*)\'>/siU
```

However, I cant get the expression to work with sed. When i run:

```
data=$(wget ${serviceUrl} -q -O -)
parsedData=$(sed '/<a\shref=\'\''\/ssl-address\/data\/([^\"]*)\'\''>/siU/' <<< ${data})
echo ${parsedData}
```

I get the following error:

```
sed: 1: "/<a\shref=\'\/ssl-addre ...": unterminated substitute pattern
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You **CANNOT** use `regex` with Non regular languages!!

Comment: @Azhy I totally can. Want to make a bet?

Comment: It's hardly recommended to don't use these together, an simple example of errors when using it : when you say `/s` after the tag name its just an space although some times there are several spaces and a lot of other errors.

Comment: @Azhy That has nothing to do with (non-)regular languages.

Comment: So you are saying that I can't achieve what I'm trying to do using bash?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do because what you've got there isn't `sed` code.

Comment: I'm basically trying to achieve preg_match_all("/<a\shref=\'\/ssl-address\/data\/([^\"]*)\'>/siU", $index, $matches); using bash

Comment: Can we have some input examples of what you are trying to parse?
I got that are urls, but they could be ralative, absolute or else...

Comment: I'm trying to read all hrefs from here https://chromium-i18n.appspot.com/ssl-address

Comment: @EdMorton `sed` is a complete Stream EDitor, you can delete all the non matching strings and save a piece of line where it matches

Comment: Input is https://chromium-i18n.appspot.com/ssl-address

Comment: Output is array of strings. Each element is a href.

Comment: @DMcg No, that's not the input and output for the sed command you're asking for help with, it's the web site you're getting your input from and a description of the storage for the output. The input to the sed command you're asking for help with is the contents of that URL and the output is that text transformed somehow. So, [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ wget 'https://chromium-i18n.appspot.com/ssl-address' -q -O - |
    sed -n 's:.*/ssl-address/data/\([^'\'']*\).*:\1:p'
AC
AD
AD/Canillo
AD/Encamp
```

I see you're getting some answers using double quotes instead of single around your sed script so you can do `"...'..."` instead of `'...'\''...'` - though tempting and it'd function OK for this particular current example, don't do it. To avoid any surprises now or if/when your requirements change later, in all shell programming always enclose strings and scripts in single quotes unless you **need** to expose them to the shell for interpretation and then use double quotes unless you **need** the shell to do globbing and file name expansion on them and then use no quotes.

Comment: Cheers, this achieves the desired result.

Comment: Can you extend the expression to omit the hrefs that contain "example"?

Comment: There are no "example"s in the output of the script I posted so I'm not sure what you're asking for. Once we see that sample input/output I expect all will become clear so, for the 3rd or 4th time, please 
[edit] our question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. If there's URLs you do/don't want or anything else to be considered then include it in the example in your question.

Comment: @EdMorton, you can follow that link and then reveal the page source to see the inputs. Is there a Bash Style Guide somewhere that takes this strong view that you do about the single v double quotes? I would consider readability to be far more important than portability here.

Comment: I've looked at the page, I've run my script on it, there are no "example" hrefs in the output, and the OP is asking if I can modify the script to omit the hrefs that contain "example". Now what? Using `'\''` instead of `'` has a negligible impact on readability but using `"` instead of `'` does as it makes you search the script to find why the person who wrote it needs to do so and/or to make sure there's no "gotchas" in there where the shell will unexpectedly interpret some part of it. So IMHO wrt readability using `'...'\''...'` is a bit better than `"...'..."` but it's close to a wash.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Given the 10 mins I'm willing to spend looking for it I couldn't find a reputable style guide on when to use single vs double quotes or double vs no quotes. I did find a discussion on double vs no quotes at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/133219 from the person who discovered the shell-shock vulnerability a few years ago. So chalk my advice up to experience (I've been programming in shell for 35+ years) and/or conventional wisdom and then either follow it or don't as you prefer.

Comment: @EdMorton IMHO Using single quotes instead of double quotes is just a matter of habits: there is not really any advantage in using one way quote or the other...
But I am not as experienced as you, so if I am missing something, please let me know [: (no pun intended, I am genuine asking)

Comment: Lets say you write `sed "s/Salary X/Salary 5/"`. You then realize it'd be good to specify dollars or yen or whatever so you change it to `sed "s/Salary X/Salary $5/"`. Now enjoy debugging why `5` completely disappeard from your output or was replaced by some other string depending on the value of the shell positional parameter `$5`.

Comment: If instead you had written your script as `sed 's/Salary X/Salary 5/'` in the first place then changing `5` to `$5` as `sed/Salary X/Salary $5/'` would have had behaved exactly as expected. Similarly for other chars like backticks, exclamation marks, etc. and often the bug appears based on environment variables, the contents of the directory you ran the script from, etc. so it doesn't bite you until quietly and/or cryptically 6 months later your script starts failing due to a change of environment it's run from.

Comment: Lets say you want to print "Success" when "foo" appears in your input. You write `echo 'foo' | sed "s/foo/Success/"` and all is well. Now you decide to add an exclamation mark for emphasis so you tweak it to `echo 'foo' | sed "s/foo/Success!/"` and you get crazy, cryptic output depending on your shell and it's settings because `!` can pull back a command from your history. Again, problem avoided if you just used single quotes in the first place `echo 'foo' | sed 's/foo/Success!/'`

Comment: @EdMorton, I mean no disrespect, and although I haven't been doing shell for 35+ years, I have for 20 or so. In my experience, people usually use double quotes as I did here, which doesn't mean they're right. Thanks for the link. Yes, I see the security point.

Comment: @AlexHarvey no problem, I understand and yes people do often use double quotes and every time I look at it I shake my head as I know they'll get stung by that approach, if not in the current script then in some other script. Using the most secure quotes you can for your needs (`'` then `"` then none) is like having a seat belt in your car. You can use choose not to use it and you'll be fine most of the time and maybe you even think you'll put it on when you see an accident is about to happen but your result with that approach may not be as successful as if you just always put it on.

Answer (score 1):

All right, you are trying to parse an entire webpage.
This situation require to delete all the lines you don't need.
As @Ed Morton said, you can use something else than `sed`.

Your webpage is [this](https://chromium-i18n.appspot.com/ssl-address) as you told us in a comment, so you first need do download it.
Note that the changing how you download the source of the page, you can change some thing (E.G. copy pasting it from the console of Firefox you will have `href="`, using `wget` you will have `href='`).

That said, let's use wget as you are currently doing in your question.

```
# This will create the ssl-address file
wget "https://chromium-i18n.appspot.com/ssl-address"
# This will give you a list of all of the links in a href.
sed -e "/<a href='.*/! d" -e "s/<a href='\/ssl-address\/data\/\(.*\)'.*/\1/" ssl-address
```

EDIT:

Reading your comments I saw you would like to filter some of the output (E.G. deleting all the examples link)

This can be done adding a piece of `sed` in order to delete lines you don't need.
In your case you just need to add `-e "/<a href='\/ssl-address\/examples.*/d"` so the whole line of code should be as follow:

```
sed -e "/<a href='.*/! d" -e "/<a href='\/ssl-address\/examples.*/d" -e "s/<a href='\/ssl-address\/data\/\(.*\)'.*/\1/" ssl-address
```

Comment: Cheers, this achieves the desired result.

Comment: @DMcg Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: FYI you don't need to use `/` as the delimiter in sed - instead of writing `s/foo\/bar//` you can write `s:foo/bar::` and so don't need to escape the `/` since it's not the delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this, based on that input data:

```
sed -e "s/.*href='\([^']*\)'.*/\1/"
```

It says, "match anything `.*` followed by the literal characters `href='` followed by anything other than the `'` character `[^']*` (we capture using the `\(` ... `\)` notation) followed by the `'` character followed by anything".

Note I used the `"` to enclose the `sed` expression, to avoid you having to quote the `'`.